# How to change form input value dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

My code

```
<form name="Form" id="form">

<input type="hidden" name="group" id="group" value="" ng-model="myModel.group">

<a ng-href="#" class="btn next-step" ng-click="myModel.group='live'">Select <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>

</form>
```

Before I click button, input's log looks like big object:

```
$$debounceViewValueCommit,
$$lastCommittedViewValue,
$$parseAndValidate,
$$rawModelValue,
$$runValidators,
$$setOptions,
$$success,
.........
```

But when I set value - field becomes a string.

So, hidden field should change it's value on button click. 
And it also should be available for validation by `$isValid` and `$dirty` and ctr.

So how to set value in Angular way?

Comment: Not really sure I understand what do you mean by change form input value dynamically, could you please reformulate your question ?

Comment: I just want to set a value of form input dynamically. But I don't know how to do it with angular way.

Comment: Is your input meant to be hidden? You also have an `ng-href` directive in both your  opening and closing tag.

Comment: Yes, input is hidden. But it should change it's value on button click. And it also should be validateble by $isValid and $dirty and ctr.